# Подскажите пожалуйста, настраивал gulp, через scss не выводятся изображения, так как через консоль выводится путь css/ img?

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том что путь  через scss указывается css / img, изображения находятся у меня в папке img, поэтому консоль видит ошибку, так как в папку scss я не помещал никаких img, через background не отображаются фото из-за этой ошибки, через html правильно показывает путь /img/... Как настроить путь через scss для изображений?

Comment: ../img/img.png  -  2 точки для того что бы выйти из начального каталога файлов, перейти в основную папку проекта, после img и уже сама картинка, попробуйте. Не помню что б в scss файлах отличалось строение пути

Comment: у меня вот такой путь с css файлов css: project_folder + "/css/", поэтому изображения css  так выводятся, для того чтобы отобразилось изображение, нужно закинуть ее в папку к scss, а как вы настроили ваш  gulp для css файлов и  scss?

Comment: let path={
  build: {
    html: project_folder +  "/",
    css: project_folder + "/css/",
    js: project_folder + "/js/",
    img: project_folder + "/img/",
    fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
  },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй

```
background-image: url('../img/[назва картинки]')
```

Comment: всю проблема была в том что нужен был слеш, перед img, спасибо за помощь